# C language, explain this code

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

     for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

       switch (i % 3) {

         case 0:  printf("zero, ");
         case 1:  printf("one, ");
         case 2:  printf("two, ");
         default: printf("what? ");

       }

       puts(" ");

     }

    return 0;
}
```

what does the `switch(i%3)` and `puts(" ")` mean? I do not understand how they work and what they mean.

Also explain why the output is:

one, two, what?
two, what?
zero, one, two, what?
one, two, what?

Comment: Your questions would be answered by reading any basic introduction to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for specific output.  Since you don not have a `break;` for switch conditions you fall through all the switch cases from the first match found

From [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm) tutorial,

> When the variable being switched on is equal to a case, the statements following that case will execute until a break statement is reached.
>
> If no break appears, the flow of control will fall through to subsequent cases until a break is reached.

```
switch (i % 3) {
     case 0:  printf("zero, "); // <= No break so once this get match all the below will get execute. (Till a break is reached)
     case 1:  printf("one, ");
     case 2:  printf("two, ");
     default: printf("what? ");
}
```

So in your case for `i=0` to `i=4`, following happens,

When `i=1` you get `i%3` will match with `case 1` and output will be `one,two,what?`.

When `i=2` you get `i%3` will match with `case 2` and output will be `two,what?`

When `i=3` you get `i%3` will match with `case 0` and output will be `zero,one,two,what?`

When `i=4` you get `i%3` will match with `case 1` and output will be `one,two,what?`

And note that `default` is the case given to fulfill when no case is met. but in your case since you do not have `break` , this too get executed ans results for `what?`.

And what `puts()` does is , simply put a string to standard output. In your case puts(" ") will put a space. And note that `puts()` will append a newline at the end.

Comment: Very detailed, I get it now.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yu Vincent Welcome :) You can mark the answer as correct if you think it's correct or help you the most

Answer (score 1):

`i % 3` (read *i modulo three*) is the remaining of the division of `i` by `3`

Assuming `i` equals 7, `i % 3` will return 1, because `7 = 3 * 2 + 1`

In general `puts` writes a **string** to standard output. Also, a newline character is appended to the output. Therefore, `puts(" ")` is outputting a space and a newline to the standard output. This function comes from the `stdio` library

The signature of `puts` is the following :

`int puts(const char *str)`

Comment: You could give an example, and explain `puts()`.

Comment: can you explain why the output is:

one, two, what?                                                                                                                                                  
two, what?                                                                                                                                                       
zero, one, two, what?                                                                                                                                            
one, two, what?

Comment: @YuVincent , You don't have the `break;` statements in each `case`. So when `i%3` is 0, all the cases will execute. When it is 1,`case 1` and everything below it executes. When it is 2,`case 2` and everything below it executes.